# How to add a controller to send mail

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, forms

I created form but I don't know how to add a controller to send mail with these field

```
     public function saveAction()
     {
        //on recuperes les données envoyées en POST
        $orderid = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('orderid');
        $reason = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('reason');
          //on verifie que les champs ne sont pas vide
        if(isset($orderid)&&($orderid!='') && isset($reason)&&($reason!=''))
       {
          //on cree notre objet et on l'enregistre en base
          $contact = Mage::getModel('test/test');
          $contact->setData('orderid', $orderid);
          $contact->setData('reason', $reason);

          $contact->save();
       }
        $body ='Hi admin, '.$orderid. 'reason'.$reason;
    $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
    $mail->setToName($name);
    $mail->setToEmail('mymail@gmail.com');
    $mail->setBody($body);


    $mail->setSubject('Not Support Pincode');
    $mail->setFromEmail('totaltoys.com');
    $mail->setFromName($name);
    $mail->setType('html');// You can use 'html' or 'text'

    try {
    $mail->send();
    //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');
    //$this->_redirect('');
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
    //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
   // $this->_redirect('');
    }
       //on redirige l’utilisateur vers la méthode index du controller indexController
       //de notre module <strong>test</strong>
       $this->_redirect('test/index/index');
    }
```

**form.phtml**

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('test/index/save') ?>" method="post">

    <h1><?php echo "Order Cancel Request Form"; ?></h1>

    <!-- Get Customer Current Order ID -->    
       <div class="cancel-order-id"> 
           <label for="orderid"> Your Order Id : </label> <input id ="orderid" type="text" value = "<?php echo Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('ref');?>" readonly> 
       </div>
    <!-- Get Customer Current Order ID -->

    <!-- Reason -->
    <div class="cancel-order-reason"> 
        <label for="reason">Reason Of Cancel : </label>
        <textarea id="reason" rows="4" cols="50">  </textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="submit">

    <!-- Reason -->

</form>
```

Comment: Add an action method that will point to a controller function and use that controller function to send mail containing these records

Comment: can you please give me any example

Comment: Have you got any controller?
I can provide you the code to send email which can be used in controller.
And if no controller then  first create a module with a controller

Comment: <form class="form-horizontal" id="careerform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('modulefrontname/') ?>index/sendemail"> your code...</form><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var theForm = new VarienForm('careerform', true);
//]]>   
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recommend follow this tutorial

http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-create-controller-36

**OR**

create new module that will include the controller too

http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

in your case

`<form action='modeulname/controllername/methodname' method="post">`

Comment: Thanks I know how to create controller but i don't know how to connect this form to that controller

Comment: you have to add form `action='modeulname/controllername/methodname'` this is not big issue

Comment: Check my updated question what is wrong that code. i follow this http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-collection-model-forms-63

Comment: I don't want to save db i just want to send a mail to admin

Comment: you have email code just put it there...

Comment: My problem is form not submiting

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="submit">` type must be submit

Comment: Thanks i can get value from this object right $orderid $reason

Comment: Yes you can get but add name="reason" and same for other field too

Comment: Sorry i didn't get i need to get order id & reason in that mai l

Comment: For getting the value from form you will get their field name so you must add fields name

Comment: Sorry bro seroiusely i am not getting any mistake in my code

Comment: Check my updated question i din't get any value in my mail

Comment: `<textarea id="reason"  name="reason" rows="4" cols="50">  </textarea>` `<input id ="orderid" name="orderid" type="text" value = "<?php echo Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('ref');?>" readonly>`  you are not adding name this is ur mistake

Comment: i got error Call to a member function setData() on a non-object

Comment: remove  `if(isset($orderid)&&($orderid!='') && isset($reason)&&($reason!=''))
       {
          //on cree notre objet et on l'enregistre en base
          $contact = Mage::getModel('test/test');
          $contact->setData('orderid', $orderid);
          $contact->setData('reason', $reason);

          $contact->save();
       }`