# How to store Database

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi I try to create Followup to Particular seller.I don't know how to store Database. I create one Module.

**My Sql**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$sql=<<<SQLTEXT
create table followup(followup_id int not null auto_increment, name varchar(100),
seller_id varchar(255), cus_mail varchar(255), primary key(followup_id));

SQLTEXT;

$installer->run($sql);
```

**my phtml**

```
<?PHP     
//get customer login status ?>     
<?php $myStatus = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() ?>
 <?php if($myStatus): ?>
 <p> Follow Up </p>
 <?php else: ?>
 <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login');?>" title="Customer Register">Follow Up</a></li>
 <?php endif ?>
```

If user Click `Follow Up` link then it will store Database. How to write code can anyone give some example for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add in database with below

```
 $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

 $connectionWrite = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_write');

        $query = "insert into followup "
                         . "(name,seller_id, cus_mail) values "
                         . "(:name, :seller_id, :cus_mail)";

                  $binds = array(
                      'name'    => 'name ',
                      'seller_id'   => '1',
                      'cus_mail' => 'test@test.com',

                  );

                  $connectionWrite->query($query, $binds);
```

Comment: If i click p tag it will store database

Comment: you have to add controller action there you add your code and add your required it is simple way to add data in database

Comment: Can you please  give me the example i didn't have idea

Comment: this  question  i told how to add action. in place of send email save to database http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106705/how-to-add-a-controller-to-send-mail/106709#106709

Comment: Ya i understand on that but onclick <a> tag  how i store that's my doubt

Comment: do have to send data in links too add `params` in link and get param store to database

Comment: Okay got it i will check it

Comment: I got error Call to a member function getConnection()

Comment: Ya got it.......

Comment: @Kothari missed the first line add now

Comment: How to get seller id this is my column name mageuserid table name marketplace_userdata

Comment: you can get with this code
`$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
     $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');

 
    $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('userdata'=>'marketplace_userdata'))->where('userdata.seller_id=?', $seller_id);
    $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);`

Comment: In this array what object i need to pass it store array  'seller_id'   => $seller_id,

Comment: $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read'); 
        $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('userdata'=>'marketplace_userdata'))->where('userdata.mageuserid=?', $seller_id); $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);

Comment: that is correct if the column name is that..

Comment: is it correct $binds = array(
                      'name'    => $name,
                      'seller_id'   => $seller_id,
                      'cus_mail' => $email,

                  );

Comment: yes it is correct...

Comment: But db it store Null

Comment: check for values is correct and displaying there?

Comment: How to check front end

Comment: simply echo $name, and other variable check their values are correct

Comment: It display correct id <?php $partner=$this->getProfileDetail(); echo $partner->getMageuserid();?>

Comment: how to append that table

Comment: sorry don't get you?

Comment: I am getting order id in phtml use this code <?php $partner=$this->getProfileDetail(); echo $partner->getMageuserid();?>

Comment: Then how to use this code in controoler and add table

Comment: simply place my answer add your values and make sure your column are correct. easy and simple

Comment: Thanks Bro i got it in this way $sellerid = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('sellerid');

Comment: What mistake i made here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106784/assign-seller-product-issue

Answer (score 0):

These two links should give you want you are looking for. Would have to adjust on you 'Follow Up' button.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212396/store-magento-contact-form-data-in-database

[Adding a custom function to insert contact forms to database after post action from frontend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26438/adding-a-custom-function-to-insert-contact-forms-to-database-after-post-action-f)

Best of luck!